# Zeroing theorem number after each section

Tags: sectioning, amsthm

I would like to call

```
\setcounter{theorem}{0}
```

after each `\section` no matter if `\section{something}` or `\section*{something}` is called.

How can I do that?

Comment: How should theorems be numbered? If just by their number, how can you refer to “Theorem 1” when there are many of them?

Comment: @egreg.  Even if theorems are numbered with only one number, you still can refer to them using the chapter number.  For example, if I have Theorem 1 in chapter 3, I would refer to it with simply "Theorem 1" if I am in chapter 3, and with "Theorem 3-1" if I am in another chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start, with an override of `\section` using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,xparse}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \setcounter{theorem}{0}% Reset theorem counter
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {\oldsection*{#3}}% \section*[.]{..}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\oldsection{#3}}% \section{..}
       {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}% \section[.]{..}
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\begin{theorem}[Something]
Some theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Something]
Some theorem.
\end{theorem}

\section*{Another section}
\begin{theorem}[Something]
Some theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Something]
Some theorem.
\end{theorem}

\section{A section}
\begin{theorem}[Something]
Some theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Something]
Some theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, `\section*` adds a number.

Answer (score 2):

This prepends the `\section` code with the resetting — however, I've removed the `\thesection` in the theorem numbering.

It would be easier if this requirement would not hold for `\section*` too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newtheorem{theorem}{My Theorem}
%\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}} % it's the default

\xpretocmd{\section}{\setcounter{theorem}{0}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
\begin{theorem}[Theorem of everything]
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\section*{First unnumbered section}
\begin{theorem}[A new theorem]
Another theorem
\end{theorem}

\section{Second}
\begin{theorem}[Another important theorem]
Yet another important stuff in her
\end{theorem}


\end{document}
```